# open a componet by click on text in react native

Tags: react-native

I want to open a calendar component when I click on a text.

```js
<Text onPress={_onPressButton}>Select date</Text>

var _onPressButton = () => {
        return (
             <DatePicker />
        )
    };
```

**UPDATE** : 
I found the answer here 
https://github.com/xgfe/react-native-datepicker/issues/73#issuecomment-278840899

Answer (score 1):

You have to keep a ref to the data picker component and call the method "onPressDate" using the date picker ref.

Note: @Nima i am answering this according to the package you are using (
https://github.com/xgfe/react-native-datepicker)

Check the snippet below

In constructor:

```
this.startDatePicker = this.updateRef.bind(this, "startDate");
```

updateRef method:

```
updateRef(name, ref) {
        this[name] = ref;
    }
```

DatePicker component:

```
                          <DatePicker
                            showIcon={false}
                            ref={this.startDatePicker}
                            date={this.state.startDate}
                            mode="date"
                            placeholder="select date"
                            format="DD-MM-YYYY"
                            minDate={new Date()}
                            confirmBtnText="Confirm"
                            cancelBtnText="Cancel"
                            onDateChange={date => {
                                global.consoleLogger('the current date selection', date);

                            }}
                        />
```

Call this method on click of the text or button:

```
openStartDatePicker = () => {
        this.startDate.onPressDate();
    }
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

What date picker do you use for it? Because i guess its not DatePickerAndroid or DatePickerIOS from react-native library. I think you use react-native-datepicker. It creates  new component in view so not sure if you are able to open it from different place (on text click). In my opinion React Native Picker is better because has method Picker.show() so you can display it on text press.

link to documentation: https://github.com/beefe/react-native-picker*

You have to init picker with properdata passed in array.

```
const initPicker = ( onConfirm, onCancel, dateFrom, dateTo ) => {
  Picker.init({
    pickerData: createLastDates(dateFrom, dateTo),
    pickerConfirmBtnText: "Confirm",
    pickerCancelBtnText: "Cancel",
    pickerTitleText: '',
    pickerConfirmBtnColor: [255, 0, 0, 1],
    pickerCancelBtnColor: [150, 150, 150, 1],
    pickerBg: [255, 255, 255, 1],
    pickerToolBarBg: [200, 200, 200, 1],
    onPickerConfirm: onConfirm,
    onPickerCancel: onCancel,
  });
};
```

and then on first click you have to use this function to initialize picker and then show picker with Picker.show();

Comment: I've edited my first answer. With react-native-datepicker you are not able to open picker from <Text> component, because it has built in method to show DatePicker. I would suggest to use React-Native-Picker instead

Answer (score 0):

```
<Text
 onPress={() => {this.onPressDate()}}>
 Your Text
</Text>
```